# SoapUI vs Postman posting json

Tags: json, rest, post, soapui, postman

quite new to testing, but currently Im testing rest services...

Really like SoapUI (did some soap testing in the past), but I have problem with testing one service - it is service for creating an event - have tried it in postman(working) and in soapui(not working).

When I try to run it in SoapUI Im getting error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is code from postman request (getting status: 200 OK):

```
POST /Event.Api/v1/events HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.26.2.66
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJCT0hVU0xBViIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiRE9LT1VQSUwiLCJQT0lEIjoiOGYyMTdiZWItZmQ3My00OThjLWFhZjktOWY0ZTk0YmRhMjIzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE1MTUzNTg0fQ.2uB_pPXyl3wSAqonaDb5pLAwDb-BujMIU6Rdeg_73Jw
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1d92a58e-c4de-f790-caca-fd983392a17e

{
  "name": "Michalova událost",
  "place": "AC",
  "start": "2018-01-05T15:00:39.164Z",
  "end": "2018-01-05T16:00:39.164Z",
  "wholeDay": true,
  "repeating": "NEOPAKUJE_SE",
  "description": "Popis michalovy události"
}
```

edit: screen of soapUI request added
[image]
and here is request code from soapUI, dont undestand why, but there is not the json content I added in the post window

```
POST http://172.26.2.66/Event.Api/v1/events HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJCT0hVU0xBViIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiRE9LT1VQSUwiLCJQT0lEIjoiZWJhMWVmNjMtNWUzNS00YTU3LTljNWMtNDY3ZmJhZmI5YTIyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE1MTU4MTI3fQ.s5dNZxV6NME1G8rbYrsuv8sb1nMiB8z1GSVGHe3auVA
Content-Length: 220
Host: 172.26.2.66
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

and here is raw response from soapUI:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 11:17:25 GMT

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "COMMON_ERROR",
      "description": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help? Thanks for your replys.
P.S:think it is something with that json content, cause when Im testing get methods, everything is fine and Im getting expected results even in the soapUI

MJ

Comment: what does the request look like in soapUI? Can you add an image?

Comment: sure i can, edited post and added

Comment: Is there an additional info in the Schema conflicts?

Comment: nothing, just blank space :-/